# ¿Por que bootstrap5 me cambia mi fuente?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

me gustaria hacer que bootstrap5 me deje utilizar mi fuente, importe bootstrap con la CDN que te da en la pagina:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Pero como ven en las fotos, bootstrap me cambia mi fuente:

Con bootstrap:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin bootstrap:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde mas se nota es en el miapizza del navbar.

Mi fuente lo tengo asi en mi archivo css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?

family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Intente ponerle !important a la linea del font family pero no funciono.

¿Donde puedo modificar esto? De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: en que orden en tu head agregas los CSS Custom, no lo veo??

Comment: dentro de tu etiqueta `head` donde llamas a loa archivos `css` tenes que poner primero el de `bootstrap` y luego tu archivo de estilos que implementas vos.

Comment: @daniel yo llamo a bootstrap fuera del head, dentro del body, al final de todo

Comment: Daniel, ya puse el link en el head, debajo de mi propio archivo css, pero esto no cambia

Comment: @HatoriHanso te dije que va primero `bootstrap` luego va tu `css`

Comment: CSS: acrónimo en inglés de: Hojas de estilo en cascada. Significa que la lectura de los estilos se hace en cascada, es decir: leerá los estilos en el orden en que aparezcan declarados en tu documento. Por lo tanto, si tienes un estilo para la fuente y colocas tu hoja de estilos antes que la de bootstrap, el estilo de bootstrap será el que tome la precedencia ya que en la cascada de lectura es el último en leerse. Es por ello que te indican que debes declarar primero los estilos de bootstrap y de último los tuyos.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 tiene unas variables al inicio del archivo de estilos donde define los dos tipos de fuente que usa      --bs-font-sans-serif   y   --bs-font-monospace. Intenta cambiar hay los valores a tus fuentes. Y por supuesto tus CSS despues de los de Bootstrap para "machacar" las definiciones con las tuyas.

Comment: @Daniel: Lo hice, no me funciono

Comment: @HatoriHanso si aun seguís con el problema, edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código todo lo que se encuentra adentro de la etiqueta `head`.